# Variable changing to 1

Tags: c

This is one of my first C programs. I am trying to make a guess the number game and I have used the debugger to work out that the line where I am calling for the rand_number function the variable 'r' is going back to '1'. I can't work out why.
If I put the code into the main() the program works as expected but I am wanting to use a function for experience

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void rand_number (int r) //Function to generate a random number and assign it to 'r'.
{
    srand(time (NULL));
    r = rand()%1000+1;
}
int main()
{
int guess, r, correct=0;
rand_number (r); //Run the random number function (This is where 'r' is switching back to '1'

printf("Guess a number!\n"); //User takes a guess
scanf("%d", &guess);

while (correct != 1) //Loop to give the user multiple guesses until they are correct
{
    if(guess == r)
    {
        correct++;
    }
    else if (guess < r)
    {
        printf("Too low, please guess again.\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Too high, please guess again.\n");
        scanf("%d", &guess);
    }
}
printf("Congratulations! You guessed it!");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is not switching back to 1 ... it is not really getting the value from rand_number (int r) since it is not a referenced.

Comment: The `r` in `rand_number` and the `r` in `main` are completely separate variables. Assigning to one doesn't affect the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int rand_number ()
{
    srand(time (NULL));
    return rand()%1000+1;
}
int main()
{
    int guess, r, correct=0;
    r = rand_number (); //return the value here
    //rest of the code
}
```

use the return method to retrieve the value from rand_number

Comment: you should call `srand` once per program, not once per random number

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `r` to `rand_number()` by value, that means `rand_number()` can only modify it on it's local scope.

If you want it to modify the original variable in the caller you have to pass it as a pointer.

```
void rand_number(int *r)
{
    *r = rand()%1000;
}

int main()
{
    int r;
    rand_number(&r);
    ...
}
```

Or simply return the value.

```
int rand_number()
{
    return rand()%1000;
}

int main()
{
    int r = rand_number();
    ....
}
```

Another problem is that you are calling `srand()` every time. You are supposed to seed it only once, if you keep calling this function you will reset the random number generator and it will keep generating the same number.

Comment: +1 With the `srand(time(NULL))` call inside `rand_number` with OP's _single_ call to it, it "lucks out" and works [everybody else's answer missed this point, so I'm surprised your answer wasn't the accepted one]. For grins: In the general case, it generates the same value for the first one second interval [a fraction of a second probably], and changes to a new value on each subsequent clock tick.

Answer (score 0):

In C, if you want to change a value of a variable inside a function, you have to pass a pointer to the function like this:

```
void rand_number(int* r)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    *r = rand()%1000 + 1;
}
```

and call it by`rand_number(&r)`. Another way is to return the random number inside the function and assign it to `r`, like this:

```
int rand_number()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    return rand()%1000 + 1;
}
```